# Asp.net html helper dropdown show two columns value in option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, view

I have a list of staff I want to show them in the drop-down list by two properties.
value equals id and the option text is staff name and staff last name.

Plus I don't want to use for each.

I want something like this but it doesn't work

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Staffs, 
                      new SelectList(Model.Staffs, "Id", "Stf_FirstName"+"Stf_LastName"),
                  "", new { @class = "form-control " })
```

This works but the only first name will display

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Staffs, new SelectList(Model.Staffs, "Id", "Stf_FirstName"), "", new { @class = "form-control " })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectList` constructor you're using takes the name of a property and uses reflection to locate the named member.  In your first example you are telling it to look for a property named `Stf_FirstNameStf_LastName` which I would guess does not exist.

If you want the staff member's full name then you need to provide that as a property on the `Staffs` object.

If you have control over whichever type the `Staffs` list contains then you can add a property like this:

```
public property string FullName => $"{Stf_FirstName} {Stf_LastName}";
```

Then you can call the `SelectList` constructor with `FullName` as the display property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Staffs, new SelectList(Model.Staffs, "Id", "FullName"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If that isn't available to you then you can create the `SelectList` from a LINQ query like this in the top of your page code:

```
@{
    var staffList = Model.Staffs.Select(s => new { Value = s.Id, Text = $"{s.Stf_FirstName} {s.Stf_LastName}" });
    var staffSelect = new SelectList(staffList, "Value", "Text");
}
```

Then create your dropdown lists using that pre-built `SelectList`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Staffs, staffSelect, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This way you're creating the list once instead of multiple times.  Reflection isn't cheap, so it's probably better to do it once anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.i use the LINQ way. actually, i was looking for a way to define props while I'm writing Html helper but as you say constructor of the select list won't work in that way.so this one you say is better than foreach and view models.